# Items in ListBox doesn't appear when I tried to run the project

Tags: gwt

this is my code and nothing is seen even a single word in my listbox. what's the problem?

```
idStore = new ListStore<Category>(new ModelKeyProvider<Category>() {

            @Override
            public String getKey(Category item) {
                return item.getIdcategory() + "";
            }
        });
        idStore.addAll(list);

        lb = new ListBox();
        LabelProvider<Category> lp = new LabelProvider<Category>() {

            @Override
            public String getLabel(Category item) {
                lb.addItem(item.getStrName());
                return item.getStrName();
            }
        };
        lb.setVisibleItemCount(5);
        lb.setMultipleSelect(true);

        vlc.add(new FieldLabel(lb, "Categories"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1, new Margins(10)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try similar to this:

```
lb.setVisibleItemCount(1);
```

This will enable a proper dropdown/list box. I think you also have to add your components to a `root` panel.